# How can I get a certain record’s system notes from SuiteScript?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, saved-searches

I need to get the system notes of a transaction from a button on the transaction record form.

I tried to create a saved search of type `SYSTEM_NOTE`, however, SuiteScript returns the following error when the `record` filter is used as follows:

```
filters: [{
    name: 'record',
    operator: search.Operator.ANYOF,
    values: ['2252668']
}]
```

Can anyone give me an idea of how I can get a certain record’s system notes from SuiteScript?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of "SuiteScript doesn't like it" consider "SuiteScript returns the following error..." or "*this* happens but I was expecting *that*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will receive an error using the filter shown in your question, because `'record'` is not a valid filter for a `SYSTEM_NOTE` saved search.  You can use `'recordid'` instead.  Note you should also use the `EQUALTO` operator, not `ANYOF`.

```
filters: [{
    name: 'recordid',
    operator: search.Operator.EQUALTO,
    values: ['2252668']
}]
```